# Query regarding Persistance Framework

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, persistence

I am a bit confused about using the jars to handle database part in Java development:

In my current project, these three jars are being used:

```
1) ejb3-persistance.jar (@Entiry @Table annotations are taken from this)
2) hibernate3.jar 
3) spring-core.jar (JdbcDaoSupport is used from this jar)
```

Please explain me the details usage of including these jars. (I want to understand the persistance framework in detail).

Please help.

Comment: google getting started with spring jpa.

Comment: The best place to understand ejb/jpa is reading the spec, understanding orm and similar persistence architectures takes (a lot of) time, again understanding jdbc is a case of reading the spec. These jars/libs are abstractions of the logic behind these technologies so you can also read the api and source files of the jars.

Answer (score 0):

Those annotations are "standard" ejb3 annotations.

Hibernate is the specific ORM being used (it will leverage the "standard" annotations)

Spring is providing the JDBC connection that Hibernate is using.

For more details about what each of these three component frameworks does, I would suggest you visit their respective projects and read their documentation. It's too much for SO.